# Simplify the ideal $(5+23i, 341)$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

This is possible because $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a Euclidean domain, hence a PID.

First I checked that $341^2=d(341) > d(5+23i)=5^2+23^2$.

I used the division algorithm.

$341= \left(5+23i\right)\left(3-14i\right)\:+4+i$

$5+23i=\left(3+5i\right)\left(4+i\right)-2$

$4+i=-2(-2)+i$

$-2=(2i)i$. $i$ divides $2$, so it is the $\gcd(5+23i, 341)$. So the answer is $(i)$.

Is this method correct?

Comment: where does $5+27i$ come from?

Comment: It was a typo. Fixed!

Comment: The ideal $(i)$ can be simplified further (at least aesthetically). Also, you don't need `\left` and `\right` on brackets when all you have inside them are regular numbers and letters. That's what the regular `(` and `)` are already sized for.

Comment: $(i)= (1)=\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: @SKYejin That's the one.

Comment: Yes.  In this case we could also go with $(5+23i,341)\supseteq(5^2+23^2,341)=(554,341)=(1)$.

Comment: How does the first containment work? Is it right if I guess that $5-23i$ is in the ideal?

Comment: @SKYejin No need. Since $5+23i$ is in the ideal, we must also have $(5+23i)(5-23i)$ in the ideal. This gives the inclusion immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, I would personally rather end on $(1)$ than on $(i)$. Apart from that, this proof looks complete to me.

As a little polish, I would make it clear what all the calculations are supposed to signify. Specifically, after each of your calculations, I suggest you clarify which two ideals you have just shown to be equal.

So something like this:

> - $341 = (5+23i)(3-14i) + 4 + i$ gives us $(341, 5+23i) = (4+i, 5+23i)$

and so on. This makes it so that people who read your proof don't have to keep as much mental track, and it makes it easier to follow your logic one step at a time.